# Is an empty Seq still a Seq?

Tags: scala

If I am returning a Seq[T] from a function, when there maybe a chance that it is empty, is it still a Seq or will it error?

In other words, do I need to wrap it in an Option or is that overkill?

Comment: An empty `Seq` is still a `Seq`. It's not going to error by itself, whether an error will happen depends on what you do with it in your code.

Comment: Would `Some(Seq.empty)` make sense in your application?

Comment: I've pondered this recently, as an internal API design issue, and came to the conclusion that using 'Seq.empty' as a marker for "not there" is unlike the normal Scala way. Thus, I use 'None' and 'Some(seq)' design even when I know the sequence itself will never, ever, be able to be empty. It just makes understanding the code slightly easier. imho

Answer (score 4):

It's generally overkill although it may convey some information depending on the context. Suppose you have a huge database of people, where some data could be missing. You could write queries like:

```
def getChildren( p: Person ): Seq[Person]
```

But if it returns an empty sequence, you cannot guess if the data is missing or if the data is available that there are no children. In contrast with the definition:

```
def getChildren( p: Person ): Option[Seq[Person]]
```

You will obtain `None` when the data is missing and `Some(s)` where `s` is an empty sequence if there are no children.

Comment: +1. If you can articulate the difference between the cases in english (and put it in the scaladoc), then you might have a good use case for `Option[Seq[T]]`. Otherwise, just go with `Option[T]`. If capturing failure is your goal with the `None` case, consider throwing an exception or even `scala.util.Try[Seq[T]]`. See: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala

Answer (score 0):

Seq is like a Monoid, it has a zero form.

Comment: I don't think op thinks in terms of category theory